# how to Plot on bar plot a csv file that contains duplicate rows without removing the duplicate rows?

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I have a csv file with duplicate rows (records), and i want to plot them out without removing the duplicate rows.
this is how i am trying to do it.

```
df <- read.csv("C:/Users/EDDIE/Documents/R/ok1.csv",sep=',',header=T)
df
y <- t(df)
y
barplot(y, beside = TRUE, col = c("red", "blue"), main = "export data")
```

That failed me already. thanks.

Comment: It's unclear why "duplicates" of values would not cause multiple bars of the same height or why duplicate names would not get plotted. Saying it "failed" basically says  ... nothing useful. Need better description of data and the specific issues.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear why you want to keep duplicates but not plot them, but if this definitely what you want to do the simplest way is to make a duplicate data frame, remove duplicates from that, and plot this data frame. That way if you want the original data with duplicates it's still available:

```
y_copy <- unique(y)
barplot(y_copy, beside = TRUE, col = c("red", "blue"), main = "export data")
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to keep duplicates, so I did was to remove all the duplicates from the data using `unique()` and looped through with a `for()` loop and manipulated the data using `if else{}` statements.
check the code below;

```
uni<-unique(Exports$YEAR)
Exports$QUANTITY[is.na(Exports$QUANTITY)]<-0
for (var in uni) {
sum<-0
tempVector<-grep(var,Exports$YEAR)
for(i in tempVector){

sum<-sum + as.numeric(Exports$QUANTITY[i])
}
Qty<-paste("Total Qty for: ",var)
print(Qty)
if(var=="2011"){
m<-round(sum/100000000,digits = 2)
q1<-m
}
else if(var=="2012"){
m<-round(sum/100000000,digits = 2)
q2<-m
}
else if(var=="2013"){
m<-round(sum/100000000,digits = 2)
q3<-m
 }
else if(var=="2014"){
m<-round(sum/100000000,digits = 2)
q4<-m
 }
else if(var=="2015"){
m<-round(sum/100000000,digits = 2)
q5<-m
}
}
TotalQty<-c(q1,q2,q3,q4,q5)
names(TotalQty)=c("2011","2012","2013","2014","2015")
barplot(TotalQty,col ="blue" ,xlab = "Year", ylab = "Quantity",
 main =  "Bar chart showing total quantities for each year")
```